# Problems highlighting substring in a text

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a problem with a code that I do not know very well how to solve.
The fact is that I want to highlight the substrings found in a text, for this I have developed the following code:

```
texts.ForEach((a) =>
{
    if (a.Content.Contains(word))
    {
        RenderResultSubString(a, word);                 
    }
});
```

The method with which I render the text is the following:

```
public TextGramaticaItemPublic RenderResultSubString(TextGramaticaItemPublic a, string substr) {

    a.Content = Regex.Replace(a.Content, String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", substr), new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceKeyWords), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        
    return a;        
}
```

And the delegate of the MatchEvaluator that adds the HTML to cause the highlighting effect is this:

```
public string ReplaceKeyWords(Match m) { 

    return "<mark><b>" + m.Value + "</b></mark>";
}
```

And the truth is that this works when it comes to strings but not when it comes to substrings. I think I'm on the right track, but there is something that escapes me and I can't quite get it right.

I've done a lot of research! But I can't see my failure! :(

Comment: EDITED: Sorry, I made a mistake writing the code in StackOverFlow

Comment: `this works when it comes to strings but not when it comes to substrings` - Do you mean it works for whole words but not parts of words? Also what is the relevance of `\b` in the text?

Comment: Replace `String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", substr)` with only `substr`

Comment: Side note: with `a.Content = ` you're altering the parameter passed in - might be harmless, might not.

Comment: Solved! Thanks @Harshad Raval! The @"\b{0}\b" was the problem... Thanks @Jamiec!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

The code must be:

```
public TextGramaticaItemPublic RenderResultSubString(TextGramaticaItemPublic a, string substr) {

        a.Content = Regex.Replace(a.Content, String.Format(substr), new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceKeyWords), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        return a;
    
    }
```

Such @Harshad Raval and @Jamiec comments the expression @"\b{0}\b" of the String.Format() method it's not relevant. Was inherited code...

Thanks to everybody!